# Compare a user entered name with all the names stored in name array

Tags: java, arrays

I am trying to write a program to check the salaries of 2 employees. So I first accept the name of all the employees in an array named employeeName and sales by the employees in the array named AnnualSales.
I am facing problem when I am try to check a user entered name with a name stored in the employeeName array.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Array {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int numberOfEmployees;                              // will store the number of employees
        int compare;                                        // number of employees you want to compare results to

        //Scanner class enables user input
        Scanner sp = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Enter the number of employees: ");
        numberOfEmployees = sp.nextInt();

        String[] employeeName = new String[numberOfEmployees];              // this string array will store the name of employees
        double[] AnnualSales = new double[numberOfEmployees];               // this will store the sales of every individual employee
```

This will store all the employeeNames and their AnnualSales.

```
        for(int i = 0 ; i < numberOfEmployees ; i++) {

            System.out.printf("Enter name of employee %d: ",i+1);
            employeeName[i] = sp.next();

            System.out.printf("Enter salary of employee %d: ",i+1);
            AnnualSales[i] = sp.nextDouble();

        }

        System.out.println("Enter the number of employees you want to compare records of: ");
        compare = sp.nextInt();

        if(compare > numberOfEmployees) {

            System.out.println("IndexOutOfBound");
            System.exit(0);
        }

        String[] comparison = new String[compare];

        for(int i = 0; i < compare; i++) {

            System.out.printf("Enter name of employee %d for comparison: ",i+1);
            comparison[i] = sp.next();

            // a loop to go through all the names in the employeeName array
            System.out.println(comparison[i]);
```

I just want to check whether the name of the employee is already in the employeeName array. The below *if* condition exits on comparing the 1st name in the employeeName array but I want to check the name of a particular employee with all the employees in the employeeName array.

```
            for(int j = 0 ; j < numberOfEmployees ; j++) {  
                if(comparison[i] != employeeName[j]) {
                    System.out.println("Employee does not exist!");
                    System.exit(0);
                }
            }
        }

        // compare salary of 2 employees

        if(AnnualSales[compare-1] > AnnualSales[compare-2]) {

            System.out.printf("Sales of %s are greater than %s",employeeName[compare-1], employeeName[compare-2]);
        }else {
            System.out.printf("Sales of %s are less than %s",employeeName[compare-1], employeeName[compare-2]);
        }

        sp.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: A useful read for you can find here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: you should go for hashset insted of array..

Comment: You exit the program as soon as you find a non-match. Instead, you should exit only the for-loop as soon as you find a match.

Comment: @Sentry i just your hint and it worked !

Comment: You're welcome! I thought about writing up an answer but then I would've had to address all the other issues ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't compare string with `==` like this:

```
comparison[i] != employeeName[j]
```

Using `equals()` instead:

```
!comparison[i].equals(employeeName[j])
```

Comment: You marked the previous question as a dupe (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50543239/java-getheaderfields-header-is-not-equal-to-its-value) but yet answered this :-|

Comment: This one is hidden because he's comparing array element. Not straightforward to OP.

Comment: @MạnhQuyếtNguyễn i used equals90 method for comparison. Also i did exit the loop when a match is found, and earlier i was exiting the loop when a match is not found.

Answer (score 0):

```
You need to correct this as:
    for(int j = 0 ; j < numberOfEmployees ; j++) {  
if(!comparison[i].equals(employeeName[j])) {
                        System.out.println("Employee does not exist!");
                        System.exit(0);
                    }
                }
            }
    **Output after changing this condition of your code:**
    Enter the number of employees: 
    3
    Enter name of employee 1: a
    Enter salary of employee 1: 1
    Enter name of employee 2: b
    Enter salary of employee 2: 2
    Enter name of employee 3: c
    Enter salary of employee 3: 3
    Enter the number of employees you want to compare records of: 
    2
    Enter name of employee 1 for comparison: a
    a
    Employee does not exist!
```